# Do Firestore Function Triggers count as reads?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I know what you are probably thinking, "why does it matter? Don't try to over-complicate it just to optimize pricing". In my case, I need to.

I have a collection with millions of records in Firestore, and each document gets updated quite often. Every-time one gets updated, I need to do some data-cleaning (and more). So I have a function trigger by `onUpdate` that does that. In the function there's two parameters: document before update and document after update.

My question is:

Because the document is been passed as an argument, does that count as a database read?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The event generated by Cloud Firestore to send to Cloud Functions should not count as an extra read beyond what what was done by the client to initially trigger that event.

Comment: Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Is this also the same for writing to a collection or updating a document from a cloud function? I have a feed system where cloud functions distribute to all users (Could be millions of writes). Just want to make sure this isn't included in the $0.18/100,000

Comment: @CaseyWest I'm not sure what you're asking.  Please take the time to write out a question in a new post that explains the specific situation that you're concerned about.

Comment: @CaseyWest yes, they are considered a document write. Better store such values which require high number of read/write in realtime database as it's read/write are free.

Comment: @DougStevenson sorry to revive an old topic. Is there any documentation that supports this answer? Can't seem to find and docs about it.